# Try to convert json to map for golang web application

Tags: go, gitea

I am writing a web application using golang. This app tries to use the api of gitea. My task is to get json and convert it to map. First I get the response.body and convert it to []byte by using ioutil.readAll(), then I use Unmarshal() to convert it to map. I can get the response.body in []byte format. However, there is no element in map. Does anyone know the reason?

[image: code]

[image]

you can see that the map is empty but I can get response.Body in []byte format.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - post actual code.

Comment: `json.Unmarshal` returns an error and tells you what's wrong exactly. Most likely however, the payload is either not JSON or it is JSON but it contains a value that does not "fit" into a map, like an array instead of an object for example.

Comment: Also, when you are printing bytes for debugging, help yourself and convert the bytes into a string, so that as a human you can actually read the output.

Answer (score 3):

Your picture that shows the dump of responseData byte, the first integer value in that array is `91`.  In ascii, that's a left bracket, `[`, or rather the start of an array.  The second byte, `123`, is a left curly brace, or `{`

Decoding your first few bytes:

```
[{"id":3,"url":"http://...
```

Hence, your response body is not a json object, but rather it's more likely to be a json array containing json objects.

Do this instead:

```
var items []interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(responseData, &items)
```

If all goes well, your `items` array is filled up with an array of `map[string]interface{}` instances. That assumes that all items in the array are json objects to begin with.

And if you know for certain that it's always an array of objects, you can declare `items` as this instead (an array of maps).

```
var items []map[string]interface{}
```